# Sequential Search: Input Length Isn't Detected Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, position, user-input, linear-search

I'm writing a program where the user inputs a list of numbers, and then is asked which number he or she wants the program to return that numbers position. (Ex. 3,5,1,9,12,6 --> find position in list where 9 occurs) 
I can get this to work if I hard code the list and the search number, but I'm having trouble with input. Mostly my problem is that Python isn't detecting the length of the list of numbers but I'm not sure how to fix this. 
Here is the code I have:

```
def List(line):
    list = []
    for e in line.split(','):
        list.append(int(e))

def Search(num, list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] == num:
            return i

    return -1

def main():
    line = input("Enter list of numbers separated by commas: ")
    p = input("Number searching for")

    print(List(line))

    a = Search(p, list)
    print(a)

main()
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Final Exam Practice\linearsearch.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Final Exam Practice\linearsearch.py", line 19, in main
    a = Search(p, list)
  File "G:\Final Exam Practice\linearsearch.py", line 7, in Search
    for i in range(len(list)):
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176921/2833032) has something you could use. `list.index` is a class method that returns the index of a list item:

```
>>> mylist = [3,5,1,9,12,6]
>>> mylist.index(9)
3
```

Next, a `TypeError` is raised because `list` is one of Python's reserved keywords. If you want to pass a list to your `Search` function, don't name it 'list'.

Just changing the name of the 'list' variable in the function will solve your problem. Additionally, here's another way to define `search` (Python function names are usually lowercase):

```
def search(num, mylist):
    try:
        return mylist.index(num)
    except:
        return -1
```